# Site association bonus not awarded

Tags: support, association, association-bonus

I have 245 rep on Stack Overflow and just made an account on GameDev (and here). Both of those have 1 rep.

Why didn't I get the +100 association bonus?

Comment: Says you only have 46 reputation on Stack Overflow...

Comment: @animuson: Refer to my comment on the answer.

Comment: You never noticed the different avatar, different reputation, different badge icons?!

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Different privileges? How would he upvote an answer the first time with his new account?

Answer (score 6):

Your [StackOverflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126849/user1126849) shows you only have 46 reputation. Also, the [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126849/user1126849?tab=reputation) shows you never gained more than that.

Comment: I wish I had gotten to this before it got downvoted.

This is me:
http://stackoverflow.com/users/2258552/user2258552

This is also me:
http://stackoverflow.com/users/1126849/user1126849

I appear to have split my profile somehow. I'm logged into both currently. I got the bonus on the sites that are associated with the first profile, but not those with the second profile.

Comment: A split personality! Sorry, we can't help you with that ;). Click `Contact us` at the bottom of this page and request profile merging. Usually they will fix it in a few days.